# Strange behavior of \href on .pdf file in hyperref

Tags: hyperref

Thank you for taking the time to read this problem.
I want to use `\href` to create a hyperlink to my other PDF file. Unfortunately, there are two cases of problems:

1. If I use `\href{run:\path\to\file}{text}`, the code works fine for PDF readers like Adobe Acrobat or SmartPDF. However, they don't work on web browsers.
2. When I use `\href{\raletive-path\to\file}{text}` when using the `.txt` suffix, the code works well. However, when using `.pdf` suffix, the href link will be considered as an `anchor` and the link does not work. Meanwhile, `\url` command does not have this problem.

Here is some test code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=green,CJKbookmarks=True]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
    \section{Problem}
    When use URL .pdf: \url{./test/test.pdf} \\
    When use href .pdf: \href{./test/test.pdf}{testfile}\\ 
    \newline
    When use URL .txt: \url{./test/test.txt} \\
    When use href .txt: \href{./test/test.txt}{testfile}\\ 
    \newline
    When use URL without extension: \url{./test/test} \\
    When use href without extension: \href{./test/test}{testfile}\\ 
\end{document}
```

Environment setting:

> Windows 2004 64-bit
> TexLive 2019
> XeTex, pdfTex

Comment: the result of your \url is not a real URI, it is missing the protocol. If it works it is more by chance or because the pdf viewer is guessing right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile the following document to understand the behavior of `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=red,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=green,CJKbookmarks=True]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\section{Problem}
When use URL .pdf: \url{./test/test.pdf} \\
When use href .pdf: \href{./test/test.pdf}{testfile}\\ 
\newline
When use URL .txt: \url{./test/test.txt} \\
When use href .txt: \href{./test/test.txt}{testfile}\\ 
\newline
When use URL without extension: \url{./test/test} \\
When use href without extension: \href{./test/test}{testfile}\\ 
\end{document}
```

The produced PDF is now uncompressed so you can open it with your favorite text editor.

First you find all the annotations (this is what links are called in a PDF document) added to the page by their stream number  (in the same order as in the source file):

```
/Annots [ 7 0 R 8 0 R 9 0 R 10 0 R 11 0 R 12 0 R ]
```

Then you find the stream object (from #7 to #12):

```
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Border[0 0 0]/H/I/C[0 1 1]
/Rect [227.749 632.204 308.197 643.329]
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(./test/test.pdf)>>
>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Border[0 0 0]/H/I/C[0 .5 .5]
/Rect [223.626 620.526 254.455 631.374]
/Subtype/Link/A<</F(./test/test.pdf)/S/GoToR/D[0/Fit]>>
>>
endobj
9 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Border[0 0 0]/H/I/C[0 1 1]
/Rect [226.366 597.722 306.813 607.464]
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(./test/test.txt)>>
>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Border[0 0 0]/H/I/C[0 1 1]
/Rect [222.242 586.598 253.071 595.509]
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(./test/test.txt)>>
>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Border[0 0 0]/H/I/C[0 1 1]
/Rect [288.411 561.857 347.937 571.598]
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(./test/test)>>
>>
endobj
12 0 obj
<<
/Type /Annot
/Border[0 0 0]/H/I/C[0 .5 .5]
/Rect [284.288 550.732 315.116 559.643]
/Subtype/Link/A<</F(./test/test.pdf)/S/GoToR/D[0/Fit]>>
>>
endobj
```

In each case, streams contains a `/Subtype/Link/A` annotation.

All links produced by `\url` and the link to `.txt` file produced by `\href` are `/Type/Action/S/URI` (a link to an external URI/URL) with correct link URL (relative URL).

The explicit link to `.pdf` file produced by `\href` (#7 obj) is `F(./test/test.pdf)/S/GoToR/D[0/Fit]` (a link to an external PDF file). This is convenient because the PDF viewer then knows that it can open the file itself.

The link from a URL without an extension generated by `\href` looks weird (the `.pdf` extension is added to the link).

### Note about PDF viewer of web browers

In PDF viewer of web browsers, if your base URL (the URL of your document) uses the `file:` scheme, all relative links seem disabled (presumably for security reasons).

Comment: So is the tl;dr: "You should use the .pdf extension on your links"?