# Add relative href web link to pdf document

Tags: hyperref, urls, href

How do I add a relative href *web* link to a .pdf document?

I want to post sets of question/answer pairs to my web site.  For example, `http://foo.com/W22/Tests/Q1.pdf` and `http://foo.com/W22/Tests/Q1_solutions.pdf`.  Furthermore, I want `Q1.pdf` to contain a *relative* link to `Q1_solutions.pdf`.  The relative link is important because I want to be able to move the files to different directories (e.g., `W22` to `F22`) without breaking the links.

Adding `\href{Q1_solutions.pdf}{(solutions)}` to the `Q1` document does insert a link into the .pdf, but nothing happens when I click on the link.

Adding `url{Q1_solutions.pdf}` creates a link with the desired behavior (opening `Q1_solutions.pdf`), but the displayed test is the file name instead of "(solutions)".

I think this article discusses the source of the problem, but I don't understand what I'm supposed to do to fix the problem:  [Strange behavior of \href on .pdf file in hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554845/strange-behavior-of-href-on-pdf-file-in-hyperref)

(On a related note: When viewing a hyperlink inside a .pdf from a web browser, is there a way to see the link's target before clicking on it?)

Comment: You could try `{\hypersetup{extension=}\href{Q1_solutions.pdf}{solutions}}` hyperref will then create an URI link.

Comment: Interesting:  It works on Chrome, but not on Safari.  How do I generate an uncompressed .pdf so I can see what kind of link is actually being generated (like was done in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554845/strange-behavior-of-href-on-pdf-file-in-hyperref?

Comment: I use `\RequirePackage{expl3}\ExplSyntaxOn\pdf_uncompress:\ExplSyntaxOff` or `\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}\DeclareDocumentMetadata{uncompress}`. But as I commented below the question: the URI link has no protocol and that is a bit dubious. You could try to set the baseurl.

Comment: Using `baseurl` allows the href to work in Chrome; but it still doesn't work in Safari.  Also, I'm trying to avoid hard-coding the base in the pdf so I can easily move the documents.  Is the problem that a relative or site-relative *web* URL doesn't make sense for a .pdf?

Comment: Well the right link type would be GoToR as you would get with \href{Q1_solutions.pdf}{(solutions)}. It is a problem of the viewers if they don't handle this correctly and not of the pdf format.  (with adobe this works fine).

Comment: That's what I'm beginning to suspect.  Thanks.

Comment: I posted a new, non-latex question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70959727/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-relative-web-url-in-a-pdf-document

Comment: Oh, I hadn't really registered that you open the pdf through a browser plug-in. That naturally adds some complications.